# Ruby Tutorial Chapter 5.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

On the topic 5.7 Showing Posts, after creating the `show.html.erb` file I am supposed to get the error: `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError` when submiting the form, but instead i get `NoMethodError` in `Posts#show`.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong, or a solution to this?

```
def PostsController < ApplicationController

    def new
    end

    def create
       @post = Post.new(post_params)
       @post.save
       redirect_to @post
    end

   private
   def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
   end

   def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you show your code for `Posts#show`?

Comment: We can't help you without more information. See http://sscce.org/

Comment: Here is the code of show.html.erb: http://imgur.com/1eqcR1K

Comment: Here is the code of posts_controller.rb: http://imgur.com/Yb8zeU9

Answer (score 3):

your show method is private, move it above the private keyword in your controller and you should be all set.  Like below..

```
def PostsController < ApplicationController

   def new
   end

   def create
     @post = Post.new(post_params)
     @post.save
     redirect_to @post
  end

   def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def post_params
     params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```

Comment: it solved the problem thank you! but it was supposed to appear this error: ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError and it appears this: http://imgur.com/1yY8fD3

Comment: it will not show that error since you have `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)` in your post_params.  The step you are on doesn't have that part yet.  So you are allowing the attribs. So it looks like you are ahead of yourself.  since that step in the tutorial had params[:post] in the example which would cause that error

Answer (score 1):

When you use `private`, all of the methods below `private` is going to be a private method. 
However, an alternative would be to just say `private :post_params` in order to make just `post_params` private.

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Declaring_Visibility

Comment: Sorry, I meant post_params being private. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `show` method defined in your `PostsController`.

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Yes i have that method

Comment: I'd recommend adding the code to the question. Also, I notice you have  commented out the `#@post` in the `show` method definition. Is your view trying to access the `@post` object? That would raise the exception you're seeing

Comment: that was the code of PostsController, sorry it was my fault. this link is the show.html.erb: http://imgur.com/1eqcR1K

Comment: Did you uncomment `@post` definition in the controller? And if so do you still get an error?

Comment: i just commented that to post it here, for some reason it was giving me an error about the "at sign" so i just hashtagged all the "at signals". In my code its nothing commented. i am new to ruby but i am conversant to programming.

Comment: You need to post more information. I suggest tracing your steps through the Ruby guide, make sure you haven't missed anything...

Comment: Take a look at the topic 5.7 Showing Posts, this is where i lost myself in the tutorial: "If you submit the form again now, Rails will complain about not finding the show action. That's not very useful though, so let's add the show action before proceeding." Do i need to do anything in this step? Or just skip to the next step that is to add the show action to PostsController?

Comment: Nope, nothing else besides creating the `show` method and view

Comment: I'll check from the beginning then, maybe i missed something or i did something wrong, thank you for your time!